# Python multiprocessing queue generating strange data behavior

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm working with a little project that is essentially one RPi2 distributing data to four RPi1. This is done via socket, and every client that connects to the RPi2 gets its own process. There are also one process capturing images and one waiting for new clients(on the RPi2).
The capture process sends four(at most) vectors to the "client processes" and they send to the (ecery) RPi1:s via socket.

My problem is: When I run more than one client, there seem to be some kind of communication fault, ether in the IPC or the socket. Because data that are supposed to be sent to RPi1_A ends up on RPi1_B.

Can it have something to do with the queue going between processes that aren't in a Parent-Child relation?

Some snippets from the code:

```
# Create a list of queues
Main_Queue = [Queue(IPC_QUEUE_SIZE)]*MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS

#Creation of Camera process:
Camera_process = Process(target=Camera_capture, args=(Main_Queue,Client_Update_Queue, ))


#Wait for client snippet:
conn, addr = s.accept()
p.append((Process(target=clientthread, args=(conn , Main_Queue[nr_of_clients] ,Client_Update_Queue, sock_lock, )),addr[0],addr[1]))
p[len(p)-1][0].start()
nr_of_clients = nr_of_clients + 1
```